# Declaring an INT to VARCHAR for a Parameter in SQL Server 2008 for Crystal Reports

Tags: t-sql, crystal-reports

I have a field `invoices.return` which is an integer 0 or 1. I need to set it to a parameter (this will go into crystal reports once done) so I have it like this:

```
SET @InvoiceType = '%{InvoiceType}%';
Select statement is:
, CASE WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),invoices.revenue) = '1'
         OR CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),invoices.revenue) = 'BILLED' THEN 'BILLED' 
       WHEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),invoices.revenue) = '0' OR 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),invoices.revenue) = 'PENDING' THEN 'PENDING'
                    End AS 'InvoiceType'
```

Comment: It will help people a lot if you format your code. You can edit your post to mark the relevant pieces of text as code.

Comment: So what is the problem here? You didnt post any error message